# funny behaviour when editing a csv file in excel and then doing some data filtering in pandas

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I was wondering why I get funny behaviour using a csv file that has been "changed" in excel.

I have a csv file of around 211,029 rows and pass this csv file into pandas using a Jupyter-notebook

The simplest example I can give of a change is simply clicking on the filter icon in excel saving the file, unclicking the filter icon and saving again (making no physical changes in the data).

When I pass my csv file through pandas, after a few filter operations, some rows go missing.

This is in comparison to that of doing absolutely nothing with the csv file. Leaving the csv file completely alone gives me the correct number of rows I need after filtering compared to "making changes" to the csv file.

Why is this? Is it because of the number of rows in a csv file? Are we supposed to leave csv files untouched if we are planning to filter through pandas anyways?

(As a side note I'm using Excel on a MacBook.)

Comment: Have you checked what you have on the missing rows after saving them in Excel? I'd guess there might be some special characters on some of your rows not being handled correctly on Excel after

Comment: there are no values in some columns of the rows...basically NaN. So it's safe to assume Excel is the problem and not parsing data through pandas?

Comment: Yes, Excel is likely the problem here, but you can verify that with your data

Comment: Are you saving the file(after filtering) as CSV or one of the Excel spreadsheet formats?

Comment: As csv,  by simply applying ```command + s```... I don't think there  save hit as anything else and it still appears as csv. I literally make no physical "changes" in the rows and the same thing will happen compared to just leaving the file untouched

Comment: Interestingly the size of the file actually changes from 5.8mb to 4.5mb! However, the number of rows remains unchanged at 211029.

Comment: The lesson learned is keep your data away from Excel. I came to that conclusion for my own uses awhile back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel does not leave any file "untouched". It applies formatting to every file it opens (e.g. float values like "5.06" will be interpreted as date and changed to "05 Jun"). Depending on the expected datatype these rows might be displayed wrongly or missing in your notebook.
Better use sed or awk to manipulate csv files (or a text editor for smaller files).

Comment: ah ok, so excel can be a problem in these circumstances? I mean I used pandas to "fix" anything wrong with rows in the csv file, however, the exact same operation on Excel ends up different.

Comment: Well this I cannot answer without having seen your data. But yes Excel is likely to be the problem. Open your csv file (or an extract) in a text editor before and after opening with Excel. Check for NaN values, separators, and special characters.

Comment: ah ok, as an FYI, the size of the file actually changes from 5.8mb to 4.5mb. However, the number of rows remains unchanged at 211029 in both files.